# Turning off splitting lines in vim

Tags: vim

One of the most annoying features of vim is splitting lines. For some reasons someone found it would be good to split lines even in whitespace sensitive formats. For example changing:

```
echo very-long-string > file
```

to

```
echo
very-long-string
> file
```

How to turn it off?

**Edit**: It is not visual wrap - it is wrapped in file (i.e. vim inserts \n in file if it considers line too long). Wrapping long lines is sane and while one may want to turn of I can live without it.

Comment: Try moving your .vimrc to the side and then opening a non-mangulated copy of your file. Vim shouldn't be adding newlines just because it thinks they should be there.

Comment: Does the `very-long-string` contains invisible characters like 0x10 and 0x13 ? As pboi wrote, vim doesn't add characters.

Comment: Find what textwidth is set at:
:set Make it wider:
:set textwidth=160

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`set formatoptions-=tc`

See `:help fo-table` for more info.

Wim's suggestion of `set textwidth=0` should have the same effect, though a lot of annoying filetype plugins will undo that for you. (Ugh.)

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are talking about the feature where long lines are visually "wrapped" to be shown on multiple lines. (This does not interfere with the content of the file though, it is just the way the text is presented visually.) Issue the following command to turn of this feature:

```
:set nowrap
```

If you are seeing that vim is really splitting lines automatically (not just visually but by actually inserting line breaks) then you must have configured vim to limit text width; this is not enabled by default. In that case you can disable it again like this:

```
:set textwidth=0
```

Edit your `.vimrc` configuration file to make these changes permanent.

Comment: No - I mean wrapped in file (even it is intended properly). Wrapping visualy is quite sane. Wrapping in file is imho insane for source/configuration files with few exceptions.

Comment: it seems that it is enabled on gentoo as my .vimrc contains `set backupdir=/tmp` only..